# How to store a global state for each component, that remains even when changing page in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a system that implements the features of Gmail, the database is firebase firestore.

I have a **conversations** component which contains a list of contacts queried from Firestore.  Then I have multiple **conversation** components (children of the **conversations** component) which has a realtime Firestone listener for the messages of the conversation.

So the structure is this: **conversations**->**conversation**

My question is this one: how can I keep the listeners alive along with the data, even when the user navigates to a different page on the same website.

I tried using a global context containing all the listeners (can add up to a lot!) and data in one state.  The problem with this is that all the components (**conversation**) refresh when just one new message comes in!

Is there a way of keeping components alive forever ? Is there a way of generating separate global contexts depending on the number of conversations ?

Is even possible to find a solution to this problem ? (I've been burning my mind trying to find a solution!)
thanks a lot.

Comment: Either pass the data as props to every `conversation` component. Or use a separate context for each one. Just because you have a global state doesn't mean you have to share (all of) it with each and every component.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many conversations there are, so I cannot generate them in advance, that's the problem!

Comment: You don't need to generate them in advance. You can re-use the same context once for each conversation. Just make one context that has only the data needed for one conversation, then wrap every conversation component in it and pass the data specific to that conversation to said context.

Comment: You can even nest the same context inside itself multiple times, and a component will always see the data from the one "closest" to it up the tree.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I think I will put the **conversations** component in the component who holds the context provider:

Comment: So the **conversations** component will always be active at the root of the app, it will just be hidden or visible, on whatever page the user is on.  Thanks for your help !